# Reading property file in windows batch and retrieving the version information

Tags: batch-file

I have a properties file build.properties with following information :

```
conf.major.number=1
conf.minor.number=0
core.major.number=3
core.minor.number=2
```

And I want my batch script to fetch the values from conf.major.number and conf.minor.number and result the output as 1.0 and set it to a variable "version"

and when I give echo %version% the output shoud be 1.0

```
for /f "skip=1 delims== tokens=2" %%a in (build_info.properties) DO (set "version=%%a")
echo %version%

core.major.number=1
core.minor.number=0
```

The above lines should be ignored and I dont know how to skip reading those lines.

Kindly help,

Thanks

Here is the solution and it works perfectly thanks @JosefZ

```
@ECHO OFF SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set VER_FILE="tldconfrev.number"
set /p id=Enter Ant target to be called "revision" or "hi": 
set /p flag=Do you want the version file to be updated to perforce (Y/N): 
echo(%id%
if /I "%id%"=="revision" (
  if /I "%flag%"=="Y" (
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (
    'type "build_info.properties"^|find "="'
  ) DO (
  set "_%%a"
)
set _
set "version=!_conf.major.number!.!_conf.minor.number!"
echo version=!version!
pause
)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next approach:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
      'type "D:\bat\files\build_info.properties"^|find "="'
    ) DO (
  set "_%%a"
)
set _
set "version=%_conf.major.number%.%_conf.minor.number%"
echo version=%version%
```

**Output**:

```
==>D:\bat\SO\32266650.bat
_conf.major.number=1
_conf.minor.number=0
_core.major.number=3
_core.minor.number=2
version=1.0

==>
```

**Edit** with respect to your comment (next, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32266650/edit) and add the code there, please):

```
@ECHO OFF SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set VER_FILE="tldconfrev.number"
set /p id=Enter Ant target to be called "revision" or "hi": 
set /p flag=Do you want the version file to be updated to perforce (Y/N): 
echo(%id%
if /I "%id%"=="revision" (
  if /I "%flag%"=="Y" (
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (
        'type "build_info.properties"^|find "="'
      ) DO (
      set "_%%a"
    )
    set _
    set "version=!_conf.major.number!.!_conf.minor.number!"
    echo version=!version!
    pause
  )
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: to keep it shorter (I assume there are more than those four lines in the file), you could use `find "conf.m"` instead of `find "="`

Comment: @JosefZ, your code works fine but when I implement the same thing in my code it does not show the version

Comment: @ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

    set VER_FILE="tldconfrev.number"
    set /p id=Enter Ant target to be called "revision" or "hi": 
    set /p flag=Do you want the version file to be updated to perforce (Y/N): 
    echo %id%

    if /I %id%==revision (
 if /I %flag%==Y (
   for /f "delims=" %%a in (
      'type "build_info.properties"^|find "="'
    ) DO (
     set "_%%a"
   )
   set _
   set "version=%_conf.major.number%.%_conf.minor.number%"
   echo version=%version%
      pause
     )
    )
    )

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to post the code in the right way. The above code can be directly copy pasted to try it out.

Comment: you fell into the [delayed expansion trap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: Any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: @Stephan I don't agree fairly. We need `"="` to perform `set "_%%a"` command properly. However, `^|find "conf.m"^|find "="` could narrow number of `_variables`

Comment: @JosefZ: depends on the file content. Nearly idiot-proof would be `findstr /b "conf\.m..or\.number="`

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to skin a cat - here are two more:

A:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("build_info.properties") do set %%a
echo Version is "%conf.major.number%.%conf.minor.number%"
pause
```

B:

```
@echo off
<build_info.properties (
set /p maj=
set /p min=
)
set %maj%
set %min%
echo Version is "%conf.major.number%.%conf.minor.number%"
pause
```